# convert CertStore into X509Certificate[ ] array JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, certificate, bouncycastle, keystore

I made a cert store and want to add another certificate from another function in this class.

Make chain in class 1 with `caCert` and `intermediateCert`:

```
List<X509Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
certList.add(0, interCert);
certList.add(1, caCert);
Store<X509Certificate> certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
certStore = new JcaCertStoreBuilder().addCertificates(certs).build();
```

I want to add a new build user certificate in class 2:

```
certStore = new JcaCertStoreBuilder().addCertificate(certHolder).build();
```

To save the new key to my `KeyStore` I need an array of the certificates `(X509Certificate[])`. How can I convert the certStore file to an array to get the privatekeyentry working?

```
PrivateKeyEntry privKeyEntry = new PrivateKeyEntry(pair.getPrivate(), chain);
store.setEntry(alias, privKeyEntry, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(storePassword));
```

Comment: Are you using bouncycastle?

Comment: Yes, I do use bouncycastle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using **BouncyCastle 1.56** and **JDK 1.7**.

I think the easiest way is to get all the certificates from the cert store and add them to an array (instead of creating another cert store and converting).

To get all the certificates in the cert store, you can do:

```
// get all certificates in certStore
Collection<? extends Certificate> allCerts = certStore.getCertificates(null);
```

Some implementations don't accept the `null` argument. In this case, you must create a selector like this (using `java.security.cert.X509CertSelector` class):

```
Collection<? extends Certificate> allCerts = certStore.getCertificates(new X509CertSelector() {
    @Override
    public boolean match(Certificate cert) {
        // match all certificates (so it'll return all of them)
        return true;
    }
});
```

After that, `allCerts` will have the 2 certificates that are in `certStore`.

Now you create your array and add all the certificates you need:

```
// create array
X509Certificate[] certificatesArray = new X509Certificate[3];

// add certificates in allCerts (the 2 that were in certStore)
int i = 0;
for (Certificate c : allCerts) {
    certificatesArray[i] = (X509Certificate) c;
    i++;
}

// add the new certificate (newCert being a X509Certificate)
certificatesArray[2] = newCert;
```

---

**Note:**
If your new certificate's type is a `org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder`, you can convert it to a `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` using the `org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter` class:

```
X509CertificateHolder certHolder = ...;
X509Certificate cert = new JcaX509CertificateConverter().getCertificate(certHolder);
```

Or you can do it manually with a `java.security.cert.CertificateFactory`:

```
X509CertificateHolder certHolder = ...;
CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) f.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(certHolder.getEncoded()));
```